# Why is my yes(Y) not working but my no(N) working

Tags: c

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float fever ;

    printf("do you have fever? Enter Y or N: ");
    scanf("%f", &fever);
    
    if(fever =='y') {
        printf("you have symptom\n");
    } 
    else {
        printf("you dont have symptom\n");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Can you run it in a single step debugger and see what the value of `fever` actually is and what it gets compared to? You've got some float/char/pointer badness going on, but a single step debugger and some watch statements should make everything clear to you. (and welcome to stack exchange!)

Comment: You know the difference between a `float` variable and a single `char`?

Comment: `float`-> `char` and `%f` -> `%c`

Comment: This is a good example of why we should not ignore the return value from `scanf()`.  If you'd inspected that rather than throwing it away, you'd have discovered the problem much quicker.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of fever is not correct. It should be `char` as per your input.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 char fever ;

 printf("do you have fever? Enter Y or N: ");
 scanf("%c", &fever);

 if(fever =='y' || fever == 'Y') {
     printf("you have symptom\n");
 } 
 else {
     printf("you dont have symptom\n");
 }

 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Suggest sentence explaining that `"%c"` (along with `"%[..]"` and `"%n"`) do not ignore leading whitespace and `" %c"` will be needed if input with other specifiers is mixed with calls using `" %c"` to avoid reading whitespace instead of input. (may avoid another duplicate question later...) Though your use is correct as there is no prior call to `scanf()`.

Answer (score 0):

instead of float fever use char or boolean type of variable, it's easier to use char here

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
 char user_input ;

 printf("do you have fever? Enter Y or N: ");
 scanf("%c", &user_input);

 if(user_input =='y' || user_input == 'Y') {
     printf("you have symptom\n");
 } 
 else if(user_input == 'n' || user_input == 'N') {
     printf("you dont have symptom\n");
 }
 else {
     printf("please enter 'Y' or 'N'")
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Replace `elif` with `else if`.